# Proper attribute initialization in Rails when an attribute is wrapped by another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose we have the following classes

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :bars, :bazs

  def bars=(bars)
    baz = []
    bars.each { |b| barz << Baz.new(bar:b, magic_number: 123) }
  end

  def bars
    bazs.map(&:bar)
  end
end

class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesible :name
end

class Baz < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesible :magic_number, :bar
  has_one :bar
end
```

which is the "rails" way to declare an initialization method so when a Foo is created from a hash the bazs are initialized. For example

```
Foo.new(name:"foo", bars:[Bar.new(name:"b1"), Bar.new(name:"b2")])
```

You cannot use `after_initialize` because `self[:bars]` returns nil. The other option is to overwrite the `initialize` method but it is not recomended by the Rails documentation and I cannot use `barz=` because after initialization `barz` returns `nil`, I have to use `self[:barz]=`. The other option would be to declare a class constructor method that does the proper initialization by calling the setter but it does not seem to be the Ruby way (`Foo.from(name:"foo", bars:[Bar.new(name:"b1"), Bar.new(name:"b2")])`).

Thanks

Comment: Is it `attr_accessible :name, :bars, :barz`, `barz = []` and `bars.each { |b| barz << Baz.new(bar:b, magic_number: 123) }`?

Answer (score 0):

OK What I finally did was to declare everything as attr_accessible and override the initialize method

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :bars, :bazs 

  def initialize(attributes = nil, options = {})
    super
    self.bars = attributes[:bars]
  end

  def bars=(bars)
    self.bazs = []
    self.bars.each { |b| self.bazs << Baz.new(bar:b, magic_number: 123) }
  end

  def bars
    self.bazs.map(&:bar)
  end

end
```

One thing to notice that I didn't know was that everytime that I need to called a getter/setter it needs to be done using `self.`